# "Not Well-Formed" Errors in XML file after FTP

Tags: xml, ftp, non-well-formed

Using WS_FTP Professional, I have a backup process that runs every night.

WS_FTP basically sets up the process to FTP to a remote server through windows scheduler. 
Specifically, It sends an XML file that is approximately 2.5 megs to a server for download.

I check that the XML file is well-formed before the FTP and it always is. The problem I am having is that after is get's uploaded to the server through my backup process, the xml file becomes not well-formed. If I download the file and check the line number where the error/s occur there is usually either just random numbers/letters, a broken tag, or a "NULL" symbol.

I've checked that WS_FTP isn't compressing or encrypting the file before sending it, and it's sending the file in ASCII mode.

It happens, seemingly random. Sometimes the upload works fine, other times the errors occur.

If I upload the same file 10 times then about 8 of those times the file will have the errors and they will always occur on the same line (6481). The file get's updated daily, so tomorrow if I upload the file, I'll get the same number of errors but it may be on a different line, almost as if the error is occurring after a set number of characters (if that makes any sense).

If anybody can make sense of this I'd greatly appreciate it. It's driving me nuts.

UPDATE

I just ran a couple of tests and it looks like it is in fact happening on the same byte.

UPDATE 2

The problem was with WS_FTP. Not exactly sure what it was but I tried a different FTP client it worked.

Comment: What are the examples of the _original_ lines that are broken by upload? Can you add them to the question?

Comment: is it only ascii characters then, no unicode or anything? Try using binary transfer mode, that guarantees the encoding is preservered.

Comment: also, is it the exact same byte of the file that gets corrupted, cause that could indicate a buffering issue.

Comment: Pavel, there isn't really a pattern. One thing is it's always the opening tag of a node. So <upc>999999999</upc> might end up being <fd32NULL</upc> and then the rest of the file will go on as normal (or there may be other spots an error occurs).

Comment: ewan, I tried a binary upload and had the same results.

I think it may be the same byte but I haven't confirmed that yet. Where would the buffering issue be?

Comment: I just ran a couple of tests and it looks like it is in fact happening on the same byte.

Comment: not programming related?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Binary transfer mode** or **automatic**  If there's some UTF8 in there and ASCII transfer screws it up sometimes.

good luck.